# При записи в БД изменяет дату на дату Unix(1970)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

читаю файл csv, достал дату оттуда, проверил - все нормально.
как записываю в БД, так дата только у первой строчки 1970-01-01 03:00:00
Причем только первая строка, остальные он нормально записывает (я еще конвертирую в нужный формат дату)

Делаю так

```
foreach ($fil as $val)
{    
  $trd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($val[1]));
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(id, date) VALUES ('$val[0]', '$trd')")
  Or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

Comment: так в первой строке вашего csv, небось, названия колонок. нет?

Comment: что получится, если вывести `print_r($trd)`?

Comment: print_r($trd) - странно, но первую дату выводит как раз 1970.
в чем тогда проблема? почему он только первую дату неправильно конвертирует?

Comment: сделайте так и посмотрите, что будет `$i=0; foreach ($fil as $val)
{     if (! $++) echo $val."br";`

Comment: вообще ничего не работает? и смысл этого тогда?

Answer (score 1):

Значит в вашей первой исходной строке нет даты/не распознана strtotime() как дата.
Для проверки можете в команной строке выполнить такое:

`php -r "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('xyz'));"`

'xyz' это "неправильная" дата — strtotime вернет false — а date это значение интерпретирует как ноль и выведет Unix Epoch для вашего часового пояса.
Видимо ваш сервер в зоне UTC+3, поэтому вы получаете 1970-01-01 03:00:00

**Итого**: загляните в ваши исходные данные. Может быть первую строчку вам вообще не надо писать в базу. Или исправьте там дату.